# How add methods from a class to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a class defined in Javascript with some members and methods. I also have a JSON object that has the same member variables as my class but, obviously, not the methods. What is the easiest way to convert my JSON object to an instance of the class?

Below some code that explains better my case. I've tried to use Object.assign without success. Can this be done in a one liner?

```js
function Thing(a, b){
 this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  
  this.sum = function(){ return this.a + this.b; };
  
  this.printSum = function(){ console.log (this.sum()); };
};

// test it works
z = new Thing(4,3);
z.printSum(); // shows 7

// attempt with Object.assign
y = JSON.parse('{"a": 5, "b": 4}'); // initialize y from JSON object
console.log(y);
Object.assign(y, new Thing()); // trying to copy methods of Thing into y
console.log(y); // shows both a and b undefined (assign overwrited also a and b)
y.printSum(); // shows NaN

// trying Object.assing the other way around
y = JSON.parse('{"a": 5, "b": 4}');
Object.assign(new Thing(), y); // trying the other way around
console.log(y); // methods from thing are not present now
y.printSum(); // gives error y.printSum is not a function (obvious, as it is not present)
```

Comment: If you use `class` syntax you don't need `Object.assign`. You can use the constructor to `construct` your instance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather need to change the `sum` function to make it return sum of `this.a` and `this.b`.

Also, instead of `Object.assign`, you need to change the prototype of the variable `y` so that the methods are available to it.

```js
function Thing(a, b){
 this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  
  this.sum = function(){ return this.a + this.b; };
  
  this.printSum = function(){ console.log (this.sum()); };
};

// test it works
z = new Thing(4,3);
z.printSum(); // shows 7

// attempt with Object.assign
y = JSON.parse('{"a": 5, "b": 4}'); // initialize y from JSON object
console.log(y);
y.__proto__ = new Thing(); // trying to copy methods of Thing into y
console.log(y); // shows both a and b undefined (assign overwrited also a and b)
y.printSum();
```

Comment: I forgot the 'this' in the function `sum`, that was a typo. I will correct it.

Comment: By the way, your answer works like a charm and it is kind of the one liner I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Only add that `__proto__` is the pre ES6 way of doing it, know it is preferrable to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` (as per [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) ).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind to make some changes? Lets change `Thing` input params to Object. And then you can easily pass parsed json into it.

Is it suitable for you?

```js
function Thing(obj) {
  
  this.a = obj.a;
  this.b = obj.b;
  
  this.sum = function(){ return this.a + this.b; };
  
  this.printSum = function(){ console.log (this.sum()); };
};

y = JSON.parse('{"a": 5, "b": 4}');
t = new Thing(y);
t.printSum();
```

It possible to add object as optinal param:

```js
function Thing(a, b, obj = null) {
  if (!obj) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  } else {
    this.a = obj.a;
    this.b = obj.b;
  }
  

  this.sum = function(){ return this.a + this.b; };

  this.printSum = function(){ console.log (this.sum()); };
};

y = JSON.parse('{"a": 5, "b": 4}');
t = new Thing(null, null, y);
t.printSum();

tt = new Thing(5, 4);
t.printSum();
```

Comment: This is a solution I have considered, but I need to mantain the constructor like `Thing(a, b)` and I cannot overload it to have also `Thing(obj)`. I was looking for some way of simply adding the methods from Thing y lacks (since it already has all member variables).